# How do i make the cursor larger on my computer constantly

Tags: cursor

When I switch on my computer each morning how do I make my cursor appear larger without enabling this each time I switch on

Answer (score 0):

If you set the cursor size in your "Settings" under "Accessibility" it should stay set.

Comment: I think I have version 20.04, I have looked under settings and I don't see the word Accessibility

Comment: Weird. I have 22.04 but it seems to me Accessibility has always been there. Did you scroll all the way down? It's near the bottom.